# File upload as multi-part request in Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I used the following code snippet:

```typescript
return Observable.create(observer => {
            let formData: FormData = new FormData(),
                xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            formData.append('file', file);
            formData.append('abc', 12);
            formData.append('xyz', 14);

            xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        observer.next(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                        //console.log("response=", JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                        observer.complete();
                    } else {
                        observer.error(xhr.response);

                    }

                    return xhr.response;
                }
            };

            xhr.open('POST', url, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('access', `xxxxx`);
            xhr.send(formData);
        });
```

This works perfectly fine, but I want to do it in Angular 2 way, not the plain JavaScript way. Is it possible with XHR object here?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/arciisine/ee57727e56cbc5e83739b2c24fd69658